# On window.load, is there a way to know if a certain method is used anywhere

Tags: javascript, html

On `window.load`, is there a way to know if a certain method is called within the page, either through `onclick` events or any submit event? The calling could be done from `HTML` or `JS`.

Or if there's a way to get the entire script that would be executed on the page I can try out parsing this script. Please suggest any good approach for achieving this.

Use case is more of deciding the behavior of the page at runtime - if the method is called anywhere in the code path, then show unsupported page else continue with rendering the page.

Comment: Why cant you show "unsupported page" from the method itself?

Comment: We don't want to wait till the method is called.. We want to show the unsupported message outright

Comment: I dont know the end goal but this may be useful: https://modernizr.com/
If you know which functions use which browser features, then you can make a simple onload test function that will check if user has all the required browser features. If its about detecting your own custom methods...then how come you dont already know which methods your page has ? You made the page and loaded the scripts/templates ?